# How to export the result of image info function to doc or csv file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv, export, doc

Okay, first is, sorry if this question seems stupid for you. I'm not really a fan of matlab but I have to use it for my assignment. I want to export or save the result of imageinfo function to a doc or csv format. I have searched it and found some solutions but nothing works on my project. Thank you so much for helping me!

and this is my code

```
function varargout = ws(varargin)
% WS MATLAB code for ws.fig
%      WS, by itself, creates a new WS or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = WS returns the handle to a new WS or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      WS('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in WS.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      WS('Property','Value',...) creates a new WS or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before ws_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to ws_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help ws

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 20-Feb-2015 02:37:50

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @ws_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @ws_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before ws is made visible.
function ws_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to ws (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for ws
handles.output = hObject;
%Membuat background
ah= axes ('unit','normalized','position', [0 0 1 1]);
%Membaca gambar
bg= imread('large1.jpg');imagesc(bg);
%Supaya background tidak mengintervensi data
set(ah,'handlevisibility','off','visible','off')
%Memastikan tombol lain diatas background
uistack(ah,'bottom');

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes ws wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);

% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = ws_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
% --- Fungsi untuk mengambil gambar yang ingin digunakan
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
 handles=guidata(gcbo); %This MATLAB function stores the variable data as GUI data
[nama_file,direktori]=uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.bmp';'*.png';'*.tif';'*.jpeg'}) %Fungsi untuk mengambil gambar dan Format file yang dapat dideteksi oleh program
cd(direktori); %agar dapat mengambil file dari berbagai direktori
if isequal(nama_file,0)
return;
end
eval(['cd ''' direktori ''';']); %pembacaan path directory agar sesuai direktori yang digunakan untuk mengambil file.
I=imread(nama_file);
set(handles.figure1,'CurrentAxes',handles.axes1); %Meletakkan gambar yang dipilih pada axes1
set(imshow(I));
set(handles.figure1,'Userdata',I);
set(handles.axes1,'Userdata',I);
imageinfo(nama_file);
set(handles.text1,'String','Berikut ini adalah informasi dari gambar yang Anda pilih'); 
info = getframe(gcf);
assignin('base','info',info); %mengexport variabel hasil

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%Program save file MAT
info=evalin('base','info'); %memanggil variabel hasil
%project=guidata(gcbo);
[nama_file,direktori]=uiputfile({'*.jpg';'*.*'},'Simpan Citra');
imwrite(info.cdata,strcat(direktori,nama_file));
%xlswrite(nama_file, T.cdata, 1);
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles);
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
close all

function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit1 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit1 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it now, but check if imfinfo http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html has the information that you need - a struct should be easier to write respect to a tool figure!